# Filter array on object's array contains javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array like this:

```
let posts = [
  {title: "1", tags: ["funny", "good", "nice"]},
  {title: "2", tags: ["weird", "bad"]},
  {title: "3", tags: ["funny", "good"]},
];
```

And I want the array to have only objects which "tags" array has "funny" and "good". The Array should include all objects which "tags" array contains funny and good. Not objects which only contain "funny" and "good".

This is what I have now but it does not work:

```
let postsfilter = posts.filter(post => post.tags.indexOf(["funny", "good"]));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) along-with [`.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to get the desired output:

```js
let posts = [
  {title: "1", tags: ["funny", "good", "nice"]},
  {title: "2", tags: ["weird", "bad"]},
  {title: "3", tags: ["funny", "good"]},
];
let filterBy = ["funny", "good"];

let output = posts.filter(
  ({ tags }) => filterBy.every(s => tags.includes(s))
);

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for getting *all* items of the `wanted` array and use [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) for checking if the array contains a string.

```js
let posts = [{ title: "1", tags: ["funny", "good", "nice"] }, { title: "2", tags: ["weird", "bad"] }, { title: "3", tags: ["funny", "good"] }],
    wanted = ["funny", "good"],
    result = posts.filter(({ tags }) => wanted.every(s => tags.includes(s)));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let postsfilter = posts.filter(post => post.tags.includes("funny") && post.tags.includes("good") );
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let posts = [
  {title: "1", tags: ["funny", "good", "nice"]},
  {title: "2", tags: ["weird", "bad"]},
  {title: "3", tags: ["funny", "good"]},
];

let filtered = posts.filter((v) => v.tags.includes("funny") && v.tags.includes("good"))

console.log(filtered)
```